# How to increase the speed of a text console (kernel mode setting)?

Tags: fedora, console, framebuffer, kms

On a Fedora 17 system (i915 hardware) KMS works out of the box - and using the console (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> etc.) is very framebuffer-like. To the point that scrolling through a man page or `cat` log-files is dog-slow.

How can I configure the console speed in general? Or can I increase the scroll-speed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I used to use FB quite a bit with SuSE, Slack and Gentoo on laptops, and had a similar problem.

I appended `video=vesafb:ywrap,mtrr:3` to my kernel boot parameters and would speed things up a bunch.

More on the Gentoo wiki: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Framebuffer#Kernel_Command_Line_Options

Comment: A little more info what the parameters do, and why it speeds things up, is appreciated in case the remote website is down.

Answer (score 0):

One can also try to disable fbdev and run [SVGATextMode](http://freshmeat.net/projects/svgatextmode) (that works well on nVidia hardware) from `init` instead. It will give a native VGA-like text mode that is very fast, but modes are tedious to setup for good text quality with modern monitors and they have some limitations (font no more than 9 dots wide and 512 characters in it maximum).